# After installing nala in Ubuntu 22.04, I got a warning

Tags: apt, updates, error-handling

I install nala in Ubuntu 22.04 today. After install I have a warning on my terminal when I run the command `sudo apt update`.

The warning is:

```
W: http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

I've done the following:

```
sudo apt-key list
```

terminal shows so many pub file around 8-9. Then i command

```
sudo apt-key export 91E7EE5E | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/team-xbmc.gpg
```

Terminal show:

```
File '/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/team-xbmc.gpg' exists. Overwrite? (y/N)
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)). gpg:
WARNING: nothing exported Overwrite? (y/N)
```

Now what need to do?

Comment: No. still found this error

Comment: The answer I linked to is a complete duplicate, which have the answers to your issue. And it's not an error, it's a warning - *everything is still working*.

Comment: I did it before you comment here. Let me try again.

Comment: Then you didn't do it right, sorry. I know for a fact that the above answer (as well as several others) have solutions for this. Also, this warning has nothing to do with `nala`.

Comment: I checked again. but still not solved.

Comment: Again, you didn't do it right. And again, nothing to do with `nala`.

Comment: If you want to explain, edit your question, and fully 1:1 write which commands you typed from the existing answer, and how it fails to help. Thanks.

Comment: The suggested fix is an example. You should change both the key ID and the name of the output file. Try `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openfoam.gpg` Or move on to answer #2 which has a script.

Comment: why you are using team-xbmc.gpg from the suggested?, use your owned key `openfoam.gpg` from developer run `sudo sh -c "wget -O - https://dl.openfoam.org/gpg.key > /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/openfoam.asc"`

Comment: Its works. but found other warning for my wrong command. I'm so much beginner. 

W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: This question is now closed. Please see the many other topics on this issue, and try to understand how `apt` keys should be correctly installed now (preferably to `/etc/apt/keyrings` and not `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`, because this can be risky).